# How to force HTML table inside the div block extend only to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

have an HTML table with forms for inserting a new rows to the table on the bottom row. When a new row created the table extends to the top and to the bottom. My table is located near the top of the page, so eventually the table go out from the page  How can I make it stable on top and extending only to the bottom?  [image: Screenshot of the problem] [image: How it looks in the beggining]
CSS:

```
.table {

    margin-top: 3%;
    width:1060px;
    margin-left: calc( (100vw - 1065px ) /2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.table th {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CAF50;
}
.table td{
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="table"  align="center">
    <div style = "background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:20px;"><b>Departures Table for workers</b></div>
    <table border="1" width="700" id="train_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Train Company</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- Uses php while for displaying of the rows of Trains table -->
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
            <tr id="row<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                <td align="center" id="name<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['Traincompany'];?></td>
                <td align="center" id="destination<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['Destination'];?></td>
                <td align="center" id="time<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['Time'];?></td>
                <td align="center" id="platform<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['Platform'];?></td>
                <td align="center" id="date<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['Date'];?></td>
                <td>
                    <input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                    <input type='button' class="delete_button" id="delete_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="delete" onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                    <input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="save" onclick="save_row('<?php echo $row['id'];?>');">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        <!-- The bottom row of the table is for inserting information in the table -->
        <tr id="new_row">
            <td>New ID will be given automatically</td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="new_Train_company" v placeholder="Company name"></td>
            <td><input  type="text" id="new_Destination" placeholder="Destination"></td>
            <td><input  type="time" id="new_time"></td>
            <td>
                    <select id="new_platform">
                      <option value = '1'>1</option >
                      <option value = '2'>2</option >
                      <option value = '3'>3</option >
                      <option value = '4'>4</option >
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" id="new_date" ></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="insert_row" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row();"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: share your code too pls?

Comment: Show Some Efforts share the whole Code

Comment: @kukkuz - sorry for not adding the code. Here is it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS makes the table stable on top and only go so far to the bottom of the page, and not more. Hopefully this is what you meant.

Just add these two css blocks to your CSS:

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body{
    height:100%;
}
```

then in .table, I added display:block, max-height:88% , overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden and I changed width to 1084px to make space for the scroll bar that might pop up when it overflows.

```
.table {
    display:block;
    max-height: 88%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden
    margin-top: 3%;
    width:1084px;
    margin-left: calc( (100vw - 1065px ) /2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

If this is not what you want, try to clarify it a little more

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't change anything.  So basically the div element in which my table is located extends to the top and gets out of screen when I add new rows to the table. I'll provide screenshots of the problem, so hopefully they will clarify the problem.